# How can I set socket options on a Net::HTTP object?

Tags: ruby, tcp

I want to turn on TCP keepalives on an HTTP session.

I'm running ruby 2.6.3 on Linux, and http-3.3.0 gem is installed.

I can set the socket options on a socket object like this:

```
s = TCPSocket.new('127.0.0.1', 80)
s.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
s.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_TCP, Socket::TCP_KEEPIDLE, 5)
s.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_TCP, Socket::TCP_KEEPINTVL, 20)
s.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_TCP, Socket::TCP_KEEPCNT, 5)
```

However, I am using a library that uses HTTP like this:

```
client = HTTP::Client.new(follow: follow_option)
```

And I get back the `client` object. So, I'd like to be able to set the socket option using the `client` variable. I figure I need to get the underlying `socket` object from `client`, but I do not know how.

Comment: Without knowing what library you're using it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 1):

You can monkeypatch Net::HTTP as follows

https://gist.github.com/fagci/558f2a952cdf894f6c2d7ed9d439cfe7

```
class MyHTTP < Net::HTTP
  def on_connect()
    @socket.io.setsockopt(Socket::IPPROTO_TCP, Socket::TCP_NODELAY, 1)
  end
end
```